# How to create a transparent text box on a specific page in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css

I am using Wordpress to create my own website. I have a page like this http://www.arpandasphotography.com/about/.

But I want to make the background of the text box transparent. I tried

```
div{ opacity:0.3;}
```

in custom CSS. But it is making all the pages transparent. I want to make only this box transparent. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's because all `div` elements are considered.  Try giving a class to the specific div you want to be transparent and apply class to it like `div.class-name { opacity: 0.3;}`

Comment: How do I find the class-name? Sorry I am new to these things

Comment: You will need to inspect the page with something like Chrome Developer Tools.  As @Sid said, there are multiple `div` elements, but they should all be named.  A class-name is simply the specific name given to the text-box you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks both of you. It worked

Comment: Do post your own answer or accept an answer from below if it helps you.

Comment: Bhai Avengers infinity war dekhte jabi? @ArpanDas

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a class to your `div` element, because the CSS you mentioned in the question will apply to all the divs in your application where this CSS is applied.

e.g. 
HTML:

```
<div class='opacity-class'>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.opacity-class {
   opacity: 0.3;
}
```

The above will not apply to all the div elements but only to those that have class as `opacity-class`.  Read more about [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

use `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3)` in box Class

```css
body{
    background: black;
    background-image: url(http://www.arpandasphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Bled_sunrise2-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
div{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
color:#fff;}
```

```html
<div>
Arpan Das is a full time Astrophysics/Cosmology research student by profession. But landscape photography is one of his biggest passions in life. Arpan was born in India where he lived 23 years of his life. Then he moved to Italy for his study and currently living in Canada for the same purpose. Whenever he has free time, he tries to fly far away from the city and loves being outdoor in some mountains where he can connect himself to the beauty of the nature. Even if he is not taking any photographs he just loves to watch a sunrise or sunset over the mountains, big water waves along the sea or millions of stars over the head in a dark sky.
</div>
```